# pyQt4 DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, qt4

I have an issue using the pyQt4 library in Atom. I installed the package using the installation file from sourceforge. I have python 3.6 installed. This is the code I have now:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

Whenever I try to run this I get the following error:

```
File ".\test.py", line 4, in <module>
from PyQt4 import QtGui`
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I already googled and found a few ways to fix this but none of the solutions worked for me. Here's what I have done so far:
-Confirmed all .dll files are in the main directory(no \bin directory)
-Confirmed both python and qt4 are 64bit.
-Created a an environment path in windows system pointing to qt4 directory
-Uninstalled and installed qt4 again
-Installed qt5 - got the same error.
-Confirmed python3.dll is present in python directory

Any idea what else might be the problem? Or perhaps I should just change to wxpython?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. I don't know why but I had to uninstall and re-install sip again.
I believe I installed pytq4 before installing sip and that didn't work well.
I uninstalled both pyqt4 and sip and installed sip -> pyqt4 in this order.
Hope this helps someone.